# Variable scope in dispatch_block_t / closures

Tags: swift

I'm trying to run this code:

```
for spawn : NSDictionary! in spawns {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(waitTime * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.spawnSkirmisher(spawn)
    })
}
```

I receive a compiler error that does not point to any line of code -- just Build Failed. I can get the program to work by copying the `spawn` variable:

```
for spawn : NSDictionary! in spawns {
    let localSpawn = spawn.copy() as NSDictionary
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(waitTime * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.spawnSkirmisher(localSpawn)
    })
}
```

It seems that the `spawn` variable is local to the loop, so it looses scope inside of the closure / dispatch_block.

Is there another way of handling this situation? Seems I'm approaching it incorrectly. Thanks!

Comment: It's just a compiler crash. It doesn't mean the code is right or wrong. There are a lot of things that crash the compiler right now. If you go to the Issues pane, you can see the seg fault in the compiler.